# Survey Analysis

Tags: clustering, factor-analysis, survey

I have survey data from approximately 500 companies, and on one question they were asked to rate their priorities from 1 to 8. It's a forced ranking so you can't answer with two 8s. The issue that I'm now facing is to make some logical groupings or of the companies analysis.

What are typical strategies for this sort of analysis?

I've tried factor analysis which didn't seem to yield good results based on goodness of fit measures. The lack of fit could certainly be a function of my unfamiliarity with factor analysis. I've also looked at clustering algorithms like kmeans and while it provided reasonable groupings information criteria like BIC suggest that 1 cluster is the best fit.

Thoughts?

Comment: Was that to rank the same 8 items with all the firms?

Comment: Yes each firm had to rank their priorities from 1 to 8 for 8 items which were the same floor all firms. For example: R&D, Product Quality Control, Reducing Labor Costs, Developing New Products, etc...

Comment: My practice tells that the best, logically most suited way of clustering respondents based on rankings they made is clustering on [Canberra distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canberra_distance). Such as hierarchical clustering.

Comment: One sensible data transformation is to convert the ordinal ranking feature into 8 binary (0/1) representation. This should give you a matrix of 500 x 8. As the data analysis tool here I suggest CorEx which make very little assumptions about the data.It will group the companies and the variables such that you can easily analyse each group https://github.com/gregversteeg/CorEx

Answer (score 3):

I definitely would try some hierarchical clustering. I am not sure but could you compute a Euclidean distance matrix? Another thing which comes to mind is propensity score matching, but I'm not sure how I would approach it in your case.